# clear text in html5 canavas strokeText before rendering next

Tags: javascript, html

I am using html5 and javascript for rendering a text. I want to update content of text drawn in canvas. I use the following code

```
     var drawArea = document.getElementById('drawingPlane');
            var ctx = drawArea.getContext("2d");
     ctx.font = "60px Arial";
            var counter = 0;
            function update() {
                counter++;
                ctx.strokeText(counter , 50 , 30);
            }
            setInterval(update , 1000);
```

The problem is text is not cleared before writing the next value of counter. It is rendering above the previous value of counter. How can I solve this??
   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [clearRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) method to clear the canvas like this:

```
<script>
    var drawArea = document.getElementById('drawingPlane');
    var ctx = drawArea.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "60px Arial";
    var counter = 0;
    function update() {
        ctx.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , drawArea.width, drawArea.height ); // clear canvas
        counter++;
        ctx.strokeText(counter , 50 , 30);
    }
    setInterval(update , 1000);     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 Canvas shapes (including text) are immediately pixelated (rasterized) and cannot be edited once drawn. The only way to get rid of something you've drawn is clearing the area where it was drawn as suggested by MUG4N. If you want to edit shaped later you need to either use a HTML5 library such as KineticJS which has built a workaround for retaining shapes, or use SVG.